# Making array in Solidity

Tags: solidity

From what I have read, an array is made by using square brackets[],(`The type of an array of fixed size k and element type T is written as T[k], and an array of dynamic size as T[].)`*. When looking at this basic cryptocurrency example from solidity.readthedocs **, I cannot see any array being made, yet Function mint() seems to refer to an array (balances[receiver] += amount;)

can anyone explain what is going on? what am I missing?

```
contract Coin {

    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    function Coin() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }
    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) returns  {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }
    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

*https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=address#arrays
**https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.2/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets are not only used for arrays. They are also used for the type `mapping`.

You refer to items in a `mapping` the same way you'd refer to items in an array, with `myMapping[element]` but the data structures are quite different. Mappings are basically *hash tables* and they can't be iterated so you have to know the right key to get the data out of the mapping.

You can read more about mappings here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html#mapping-types